# Is there any scenario where SecurityContext won't get cleared from ThreadLocal after a request?

Tags: java, spring-security

For a Spring Security application using the default [ThreadLocalSecurityContextHolderStrategy](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/4.2.2.RELEASE/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/core/context/ThreadLocalSecurityContextHolderStrategy.java) to save the `Authentication` object into a `ThreadLocal` variable, is it possible for any sort of error to arise where Spring Security won't be able to clear the `ThreadLocal` before the request completes?

The [SecurityContextPersistenceFilter](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/4.2.2.RELEASE/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/context/SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java) performs the following:

1. Loads `Authentication` (from `HttpSession` via [HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/4.2.2.RELEASE/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/context/HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.java)) to context (`SecurityContextHolder`).
2. Filter chain is invoked for continued request execution by application.
3. `Authentication` is cleared from `SecurityContextHolder` so subsequent requests using the same `ThreadLocal` do not have invalid data.

In short, is there any scenario where #3 won't be able to complete because of application issue, timeout, or other? If so, how should an application ensure appropriate `Authentication` detail for the current request (e.g. ensure data is valid for current request/user)?

Answer (score 2):

Since you linked to the source code, have a look at the source code for [`SecurityContextPersistenceFilter`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/4.2.2.RELEASE/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/context/SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java):

```java
...
try {
    SecurityContextHolder.setContext(contextBeforeChainExecution);

    chain.doFilter(holder.getRequest(), holder.getResponse());

}
finally {
    SecurityContext contextAfterChainExecution = SecurityContextHolder
            .getContext();
    // Crucial removal of SecurityContextHolder contents - do this before anything
    // else.
    SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
    ...
```

As you can see, the context is set inside the `try` block, and is cleared right inside the `finally` block, so it's impossible for the context to still be set once the request processing completes.

Comment: Is there any possible outcome where the `finally` block will not execute, but the thread is kept alive and old state kept in context?

Comment: @trebor I already said **impossible**. What other word do you need to answer *"Is there any **possible** outcome ..."*?

Comment: Saying a word doesn't make it true or final. ;) I'm considering try/finally exception handling as standard/normal execution of an application. Certainly, `finally` blocks would not be executed if programs are terminated prematurely (but obviously the thread is killed). So I'm validating your assumption of what normal application execution would occur against any other possible (hypothetical, if you prefer) outcome which may cause unexpected outcomes.

Comment: @trebor if i was you, i would instead present an argument to when a `finally` would not get executed instead of just asking loose questions based on things that are explained crystal clear. If a program terminates prematurely, then the `finally` block will not be executed, but when application is rebooted the context memory is lost. If you look in the source code `finally` has no specific exception, it will `ALWAYS` get executed if any unexpected behaviour arises during the entire context lifecycle.